# webkit display:inline-block behaving inconsistently

Tags: css, webkit, line-breaks

I have a span with several other spans inside it, and I want to toggle the sub-spans between `display:block` and `display:inline`. The spans start off with `display:inline-block`, then are switched to `display:block`. This works fine. The problem is when toggling back in Webkit (it works fine in Firefox): the spans are rendered with extra line breaks in between them.

Can I make this render correctly without putting `<br/>` tags between the spans?

demo here: http://jsbin.com/omalu3/4/edit

Answer (score 1):

Any other solution would be a workaround since it's a browser bug. 
An alternative to derekerdmann's solution:

```
  #a.multiline * { width: 100% }
  #a.oneline * { width: auto }
  #a * { border:solid 1px black; display:inline-block }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround would be to not wrap the children spans with another span -- which is an inline element. Use a <div> for #a and it behaves correctly (in Webkit at least!).

On another note, the star selector is not really efficient, although I understand this is only an example so I'm not going to criticise that here :D

Answer (score 0):

Now isn't that fun.

I'm not sure what's causing the problem, but it goes away if you add `float: left;` to `#a.oneline *`.  When you do that, you could change the display to block so your styles look like this:

```
#a.multiline * {  }
#a.oneline * { float:left; }
#a * { border:solid 1px black; display:block;}
```

The only difference between this solution and your original layout is that the `oneline` blocks will be aligned at the top instead of the bottom, but you could set a fixed height for those elements.